# Why do i get : uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,foggy/0),top_level/0)?

Tags: prolog

Im going through a tutorial on prolog and I get an error.

In my file i wrote:
`sunny.`

When i run GNU, i write `sunny.` and get "YES".

When I write `foggy.` I get an error
`uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,foggy/0),top_level/0)` instead of "NO", like the tutorial shows.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial seems wrong at first sight. For such behavior, one typically writes `foggy :- fail.`.

Comment: http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/facts.html

Comment: I assume in this tutorial they just stated informally what happens not exactly what GNU will throw out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial may be making an assumption about a particular Prolog implementation.

In GNU Prolog, if you make a query and the predicate with that number of arguments does not exist, and you haven't issued any directives to indicate that it exists, then you will get an `existence_error`. What you need to include in GNU Prolog is information about predicates or facts you plan to query but may not have been asserted. It's thought of as a *dynamic* fact or predicate, and you would use the `dynamic/1` directive.

So issue the directive, `dynamic(foggy/0).`:

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Oct 16 2017, 09:23:33 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- foggy.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,foggy/0),top_level/0)
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
:- dynamic(foggy/0).

user compiled, 2 lines read - 122 bytes written, 6200 ms

yes
| ?- foggy.

no
| ?-
```

Note that after entering your last line of code directly using `[user].` you must finish by typing ctrl-D to indicate end of input.

---

As @false points out in the comment, you can also set the Prolog `unknown` flag. See the [`set_prolog_flag` documentation](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog046.html#set-prolog-flag%2F2) for GNU Prolog.

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Oct 16 2017, 09:23:33 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- foggy.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,foggy/0),top_level/0)
| ?- set_prolog_flag(unknown, fail).

(1 ms) yes
| ?- foggy.

no
| ?-
```

Comment: The tutorial is very, very old - of the olden DEC10 tymes, And a little bit more recently also YAP. A non-existent predicate just caused failure. The Prolog flag `unknown` is set by default to `error`. It may be changed to `fail`...

Comment: @false thanks. I added that information to my answer.

Comment: FYI you need to hit Ctrl-D after entering definitions with `[user].`, which signals `gprolog` to compile the definitions and return you to the toplevel.

Comment: @Desty I'm aware of that. I neglected mentioning it in my answer, but I don't think the op was struggling on that point.

Comment: @lurker I wasn't aware of it and thought it was broken at first. Thought I'd mention it to avoid others getting stuck there like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `assertz` to append a clause at the end of the database.  If you are using Prolog as an inferior shell in Emacs, you can automatically convert a clause into an assertion and send it to the Prolog process.

The following sets the keys <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> to a function which does this similar to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> in Lisp modes.

```el
(defun inferior-prolog-send-assertz ()
  "Send current rule as an assertion."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((clause (buffer-substring-no-properties (prolog-clause-start)
                                                 (prolog-clause-end)))
         (assertz (replace-regexp-in-string "^\\(.*\\)\\.$" "assertz(\\1).\n"
                                            clause)))
    (comint-send-string (inferior-prolog-proc) assertz)))

(add-hook 'prolog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a")
                           #'inferior-prolog-send-assertz)))
```